# How to get all messages by ThreadID in android

Tags: android, sms, mms

I tried to get all messages by thread id with uri：content://mms-sms/conversations/{threadId}, but it doesn't seem work and throws exceptions:

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1333)
>
> at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:182)
>
> at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:136)
>
> at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:358)
>
> at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:311)
>
> ```
>     ........
> ```

however, when I change it to content://sms/conversations/{threadId}, it will not throw these, but only works for sms, not for mms.

why?

Comment: any guys have worked on such things?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the sms and mms tables have different columns,
the correct way is to fetch each on its own, that
is

```
Cursor smsCur = cr.query(Uri.parse("content://sms/"), null,  "thread_id=" + threadId, null, null);
Cursor mmsCur = cr.query(Uri.parse("content://mms/"), null,  "thread_id=" + threadId, null, null);
```

Comment: yeah, maybe you are right about it. seems we have no other choice.

Comment: From docs: @param selection A filter declaring which rows to return, formatted as an
SQL WHERE clause (EXCLUDING the WHERE itself).

Comment: cursor returns 0 in case of this

Answer (score 1):

The above code shows syntax error like that so i changed like this.

```
   Cursor c= getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms/"), null,  "thread_id=" + messgid, null, null);
```

It works fine for me